# Nginx from .htaccess PHP8 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx-config

So I have been trying to find a solution to this over the last few days but can't seem to get it to work.

I have a laravel programme which used to run on AWS but now migrating to Azure Web Apps. I keep getting the following error: '404 Not Found. nginx/1.14.' I have a .htaccess file as follows:

```
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.env$">  
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I understand that .htaccess doesn't work with php 8 so i created a nginx.config file in the root directory with the following code:

```
server {
    server_name sitename.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I still can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess works fine with PHP8, as the two are not related. .htaccess is an Apache config thing: you've done the right thing by ditching it and going to the config.

The bit you need to replicate in your config is

```
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You should be able to do that with

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do this but it doesn't seem to be working. The Index works but it can't access any of the other pages.

Comment: The main page loads (index) but other than that, it only works if i put index.php/URL

Comment: Did you remove the other try_files? I didn't make it clear you need to replace, not just add this.

Comment: Yes i removed it. Still no luck

Comment: I can't really say without seeing everything as other config could upset things. Just double check you have everything right. The instructions are also at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/ (e.g. see the note about cgi.fix_pathinfo

Answer (score 0):

> .htaccess doesn't work with php 8

No, .htaccess does not work with nginx, it is an apache config file

Probably you need to set correctly the site root.

```
root /var/www/html;
```

Assuming that your project reside inside /var/www/html directory, for laravel project you should point to /var/www/html/public in your webserver configuration.

Look in your old apache configuration the DocumentRoot setting, it should point to public as well

Comment: The main file works. Its getting the correct files but it needs index.php in front of it to work which is unusual.